# How do I access my API if it is at a different "route"?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Let's say my current page is at the location: 
http://myserver/client/index.html

And my API is at the url: 
http://myserver/api/getMyData

How can I access the API without hardcoding it like this:

```
fetch('http://myserver/api/getMyData')
```

and instead like this:

```
fetch('../api/getMyData')
```

?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data from an actual api or get data from a json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a forward slash to indicate that the url path is relative to the domain root.

Regardless of current page location, fetch('/api/getMyData') will translate to http://myserver/api/getMyData